# Clipboard.GetText

Tags: c#, unicode, character, clipboard

when i select and copy this glyph from email message: £ (0x00a3)

and then run:

```
message=Clipboard.GetText();
if(message==""){
    Console.WriteLine("There is nothing on your clipboard.");

            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    else{ Console.WriteLine(message); }
```

reports: "nothing on clipboard"

seems that all glyphs between 00a1-00ff exhibit same behavior.

I've looked at overloads for Clipboard.GetText ... to no avail.

Comment: That's a penny, not a pound.  Probably what you spent on the email program, try another one.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
   message=Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
```

The TextDataFormat.UnicodeText specifies the standard Windows Unicode text format.
However also with a simple GetText I am not experiencing the missing char

```
Clipboard.SetText("£");
string s = Clipboard.GetText();
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

I get back the `£` char. (By the way it is 0x00A3)

Comment: copy and paste of your code works fine. however, when i copy the glyph from an email or from vim file, clipboard has nothing. any further suggestions? mind, other glyphs outside the range specified in my original question, behave as expected. problem perhaps with encoding config with ubuntu 12.04? tried with TextDataFormat.UnicodeText as well ... same ... clipboard empty.

Comment: Are you sure that you are copying text data? Is it possible that your file contains a graphic for the character in question?. Try to paste your clipboard in MSPaint. Just for testing.

Comment: MSPaint not available. However, using Gimp, reports "no image data on clipboard" when copying and pasting from a plain text file. As previously mentioned, this is happening only with 00a1-00af. all others copy to clipboard nicely and paste out as expected. Clipboard reports "empty" with that series of characters. Clearly, however, the clipboard is NOT empty, for I am able to paste the offending characters into a blank Thunderbird email and as well into a text file.

Comment: sorry, that's 00a1-00FF

Comment: on occasion, not consistently, terminal reports "Could not set X locale modifiers" when attempting to get clipboard.

Comment: I don't kwon what happen on your side, but here, Win7 Ultimate 64bit there is no problem to copy/paste characters in that code range

Comment: ok. thanks, Steve for your time. I'll keep digging around and get back for an update when i sort it out.

Comment: set this up with .NET console application ... works fine. with Mono-Develop ... works fine. I strongly suspect a bug in the mono compiler, which was what i was using at CLI. so, write it off to a mono/gmcs bug? don't know.

Comment: Perhaps you could investigate if this class is of any usefulness for you - http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.Clipboard